# Configure ReadTimeoutHandler or WriteTimeoutHandler for request type

Tags: netty, reactor-netty

I have a service that receive HTTP and WS requests.

How can I configure ReadTimeoutHandler for HTTP requests only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have configured HttpServer's timeout that to be deleted if request is WebSocket:

```
  private static class TimeoutNettyCustomizer implements NettyServerCustomizer {
        private static final String READ_TIMEOUT_HANDLER = "READ_TIMEOUT_HANDLER";
        private static  final String WRITE_TIMEOUT_HANDLER = "WRITE_TIMEOUT_HANDLER";

        private final NettyServerProperties nettyServerProperties;

        public TimeoutNettyCustomizer(NettyServerProperties nettyServerProperties) {
            this.nettyServerProperties = nettyServerProperties;
        }

        @Override
        public HttpServer apply(HttpServer httpServer) {
            int writeTimeout = nettyServerProperties.getWriteTimeout();
            int readTimeout = nettyServerProperties.getReadTimeout();

            return httpServer.tcpConfiguration(tcp -> tcp.doOnConnection(connection -> connection
                    .addHandlerLast(READ_TIMEOUT_HANDLER, new WriteTimeoutHandler(writeTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                    .addHandlerLast(WRITE_TIMEOUT_HANDLER, new ReadTimeoutHandler(readTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                    .addHandlerLast(new ChannelDuplexHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
                            super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
                            if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
                                HttpRequest httpRequest = (HttpRequest) msg;
                                HttpHeaders headers = httpRequest.headers();

                                // delete timeout for Websocket and SSI
                                boolean notApplyTimeout = (HttpMethod.GET.equals(httpRequest.method())
                                        && headers.containsValue(HttpHeaderNames.CONNECTION, HttpHeaderValues.UPGRADE, true)
                                        && headers.containsValue(HttpHeaderNames.UPGRADE, HttpHeaderValues.WEBSOCKET, true));

                                if (notApplyTimeout) {
                                    connection.removeHandler(READ_TIMEOUT_HANDLER);
                                    connection.removeHandler(WRITE_TIMEOUT_HANDLER);
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        private void closeChannel(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
                            FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT,
                                    Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER);

                            ctx.writeAndFlush(response)
                                    .addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
                        }
                    })));
        }
    }
```